# jquery datepicker in wordpress showing on second click rather then first click of textbox

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
jQuery('.datePic').datepicker({
        minDate:0,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays,
        });
```

it makes my calendar to show but not on first click

Comment: no one knows its answer???

Comment: That code looks fine.  How is it being called?  In the document ready event?  Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't answered my comment asking for clarification, but the more I think about it the more I think you're associating that code with the wrong event.

It should be run in the document ready event, not the click (or focus) event of your field.  That code means "set up the datepicker so it is displayed when the specified field is clicked"; it doesn't mean "show the datepicker now" (and so doesn't belong in the click event).

Happy to have my assumptions proved wrong.

Comment: actually i have called this action on textbox click its working but not on first click i have to click first on textbox then somewhere else on the page and then again on textbox.....means it works on the second click on the same textbox...this means that code is working f9 but don't know why its not working on the first click

Comment: That matches what I said.  _It shouldn't be on the click event._  Sorry I wasn't clear, but I can't think how to explain it better.  Move it out of your click event, into `$(document).ready()`.  Your code should be run to initialise the datepicker, not when a field is clicked.